# How does this site differ from Theoretical Computer Science Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

Question's in the title; what makes Computer Science Stack Exchange differ from [Theoretical Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Surely has come up before...

Comment: It's in the site description, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theoretical computer science is for mathematicians working in the field of theoretical computer science, at the level of graduate student and upwards. It accepts only research-level questions.

Computer science, in contrast, is for all levels of theoretical computer science, defined somewhat more broadly than in TCS. Many questions here are homework exercises, though some are genuine questions by undergraduates or by working professionals outside academia, or more rarely more basic questions by experts. Some of these questions (both by undergraduates, by professionals, and by post-graduates) are difficult enough to merit asking in TCS.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: "all levels of theoretical computer science" -- that's misleading. It's for *all* computer science, as long as we are talking *science* in the academic sense. (cc @JesseTG)

Comment: @Raphael This is plainly false. There is very little of numerical analysis, databases, machine learning, computer vision, computational geometry, software development, and so on. Maybe a tiny bit, but that's all. It's mostly focused on the more theoretical parts of the core undergraduate curriculum.

Comment: There is a difference between scope definition and what we are actually getting. The former is broader than the latter, unfortunately. But you should not make the mistake to communicate that this site *is* only for TCS -- it most certainly is *not*. All aspects of (academic) CS are welcome.

Comment: "Theoretical computer science is for mathematicians working in the field of theoretical computer science" -- isn't it also for computer scientists working in this field?

Comment: @Raphael I don't think so. If you're constructing robots, running machine learning algorithms on big data, or constructing efficient distributed databases, then I don't think you're too welcome. Of course, you could call yourself a computer scientist even though you're doing mathematics. This doesn't make you less of a mathematician, whatever you choose to call yourself.

Comment: That's an issue of semantics, then. For me, people pursueing theoretical computer science are computer scientists (it's in the name!), never mind many mathematicians marauding the field for funds ( ;) ). So, to be clear for future readers: you are welcome on [cstheory.SE] if you don't have a mathematics degree as long as you pursue TCS on research level. Conversely, people outside research-level TCS *with* a mathematics degree would be in the wrong place.